# fetch не успевает получить ответ

Tags: javascript, post, promise, fetch

Не срабатывает последняя строка при обычном запуске скрипта, если поставить брекпоинт в конце скрипта и подождать пару секунд, а затем продолжить выполнение скрипта, то последняя строка выполнится. Я пришел к выводу что скрипт заканчивается быстрее чем промис фетча успевает выполнится. Как это исправить?

```
  fetch("./file.php",
    {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formObject
    })
  .then(function(response){
    let b = response.text()
    return b
  })
  .then(result => alert(result))
```

Comment: "скрипт заканчивается быстрее чем промис фетча успевает выполнится" - у Вас страница перезагружается что ли?

Comment: Да, перезагружалась. Я же повесил событие на input type="submit" :facepalm: , не знал что он такой эффект имеет. Спасибо, вопрос решен.